# Touchpad just freezes after some time

Tags: release-loki, touchpad

I am using an HP Probook 430G, where the touchpad just freezes, after a certain point, say 3-5 minutes of usage.

There is nothing in the `dmesg`. Here is my `xinput`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt Microsoft USB Optical Mouse        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Raw Set 2 keyboard                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Camera                              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

When connected to the mouse, it works just fine. Only touchpad is an issue.